# Programming ESP32 in visual studio or visual studio code?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I have seen many programs for esp32 in arduino ide and i am familiar with it. But my task now is programming esp32 for color and brightness control of sk6812 led stripes using visual studio. i found no literature on it. Anybody have any knowledge on similar field. Also i am really confused if it is visual studio or visual studio code. Can anyone give me some hint on this issue?
thanks

Comment: search for platformio its commonly used

Comment: I suggest that you could use visual studio code. However, if you want to use visual studio, you could use `visual studio+Visual GDB` to build environment of ESP32.

Comment: Is it possible that i program esp32 on arduino ide and control led stripes from visual studio linking visual studio and arduino? If yes how can i do it?

Comment: I suggest that you could select `Extensions and Updates`  and install `Arduino IDE for Visual Studio`.